# How many numbers of $6$ digit, using $1,2,4,5,7$ and $8$ are multiples of a $6$ Digit numbers, using $1,2,4,5,7$ and $8$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I found a problem and I hope you can help me.

*Let $T$ be the set of all distinct six-digit numbers using $1,2,4,5,7$ and $8$.
Note that the numbers $142857$ and $857142$ are elements of $T$ and that $857142/142857$ has no remainder.
Find all $(a,b)$, with $a,b$ $\in T$ such that $b$ is a multiple of $a$.*

There is, the obvius answer in which $b=a$ and because of the fraction $1/7$ it's known that $142857$ is a cyclic number with $6$ multiples in $T$, but how many others pairs we can find that satisfy this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the cases $b/a = 1,2,\ldots, 8$ separately.

For $b/a = 1$, every pair $(a,a),\; a \in T$ works.
For $b/a = 2,3,\ldots, 8$, I get $2080$, $1408$, $813$, $528$, $254$, $206$, and $1$ pairs respectively (assuming that by "using" you mean
that only those digits are allowed, but they need not all be used).
If you mean that all $6$ digits must be used in each member of $T$,
then those numbers are $12$, $6$, $1$, $4$, $1$, $1$, and $0$.

Comment: Yes, I mean that I need to use all 6 digits in each number. I'm sorry for inaccuracy. But, if I may ask, how did you get to those numbers